# GENERATING SITEMAP FROM URLS STORED IN table

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, seo, sitemap

i want a php script that can generate sitemap.xml , I have 5000 urls are stored in the table . So is there a way so that I can fetch urls form the table and generate sitemap and store as sitemap.xml ?

Comment: Try a search online: `"php sitemap generator from sql"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is a way:

1) Connect to table and request all urls

During iteration:

2) Sanitize them as XML doesn't allow any special chars

3) Wrap it in xml `<url>` section

4) Echo the wrapped url, push it to some file or store it in another var for later use. I would strongly advise not to use live generation and go for `cron` and static XML file.

Details how the sitemap should look like can be found here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

Comment: can you pls elaborate your answer ! I mean with some examples aor something !

Comment: But I am not able to run my php script in xml file.
what I did was :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<?php
// connecting to db

while($query_row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run))
{?>
<url>
<loc>http://exmaple.com/
<?php 
echo $query_row['url']
?>
</loc>
</url>
<?php 
} 
?>
</urlset>